Log Username Who Got access to an Api
i just wana Log Username Who Got access to an Api into File and i use HTTP Access Logging
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/deploy/monitor/http-access-logging/
but in the log file show Just - Character Instead of Username as following:
username=- time=[25/May/2024:10:31:32.018 +0330]
How Can i Get UserName Who Called an Api into Logs ?
